# Php extension: config.m4, possibly undefined macro: LT_SHARED_LIBADD

Tags: php, c, autoconf, php-extension

i'm developing a php extension (not my first one), but today i stumble
upon a problem i never had : when i run phpize, i get this output :

```
error: possibly undefined macro: LT_SHARED_LIBADD
```

My config.m4 is pretty straightforward, i tried phpize on an other
extension without any issue, i copy pasted the config.m4 from another
extension and  just changed the names and still get the problem.
Here is the config.m4 :

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(vault, whether to enable Vault support,
[ --enable-vault   Enable Vault support])

if test "$PHP_VAULT" = "yes"; then
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_VAULT, 1, [Whether you have Vault])
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(vault, vault.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

Anybody ever had that issue? Google didn't find anything on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, phpize didn't like the name "vault", changed it, and it works. Serious WTF moment ಠ_ಠ